# Emacs 26.2 can't load init file from Emacs 25

Tags: init-file, package

The title already says the question, i had Emacs 25 and compiled Emacs 26.2. Although my ./emacs directory and everything in it exists Emacs 26.2. starts complaining about packages which do not exist, although they exist. Why is this happening? Can any one help?

Comment: can you provide some of the actual error messages you are seeing?

Comment: Please don't give us any specific details, it would kill all the fun.

Comment: as said by others, you should provide the error messages. did you try to reinstall your packages?

Comment: As others have said: more info please.

Comment: What is a "./emacs directory" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest thing to do: Recursively bisect your init file to find the piece(s) of it that are causing the problem.

You can do that by commenting out 1/2 of it, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16, 31/32,...

You can do that by using command `comment-region`. With a plain prefix arg (`C-u`) it **un**comments the region.

Once you have the problem narrowed down to a tiny bit of code, if it's not obvious what you need to do for that bit then post it here.  (And yes, always show complete error messages.)

Comment: Thanks, i already did so and was able to find and solve the problem.